# Não consigo usar os Pacotes depois de atualizar para R 4.0.2

Tags: r

Ontem eu atualizei a versão do R e usei ele normal

```r
$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)"
```

Hoje de manhã, quando fui usar, apareceu mensagens de que os pacotes precisavam ser reinstalados:

```r
> library("tidyverse")
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 package ‘tidyverse’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

Mesmo usando

```
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = T)
```

Quando uso o `library()`, tenho a mesma mensagem de erro. Já tentei atualizar usando:

```r
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
```

Mas continua com o mesmo efeito. Procurando o caminho das library, antes aparecia isso:

```r
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/usuario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                    
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                           "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Tentei alterar para:
`.libPaths(R.home("library"))` e rodar de novo o `update` e o `install` packages, mas continua com o mesmo erro.

Agora o libPaths, só mostra isso.

```r
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/lib/R/library"            "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Uso Linux Mint 19.3.

A pasta com as libraries da versao 3.6 ainda está no mesmo diretório.

EDIT -------

Não consigo nem remover os pacotes

```
> .libPaths("/home/usuario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0")
> library("tidyverse")
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 package ‘tidyverse’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

---

Já exclui o R e o RStudio e ainda está dando esse erro. A mesma coisa.

Comment: Pra ser sincero eu não sei bem o motivo. Mas tente remover o pacote antes de instalá-lo nvoamente. use `remove.packages()`

Comment: Não consigo também. `> remove.packages("tidyverse")
Removing package from ‘/home/usuario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)`

Comment: Já tentou apagar o diretório com os pacotes da versão antiga e depois reinstalar?

Comment: @JorgeMendes fiz isso. Removi manualmente e ainda deu erro. Depois de muito mexer, agora pouco deu certo. Nem sei o que fiz de diferente.

Comment: Hoje já voltaram os problemas de "Erro: package ‘Matrix’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it"

Comment: Tente `Rscript -e 'install.packages("tidyverse")'` na linha de comando.